# The "Applications" menu does not open

Tags: applications

In fact the menu is open, but it's clear I can not see it, because I give the SUPER + SPACE command and write the name of a program and press enter, the program opens.

> **Português:**
>  De fato, o menu é aberto, mas eu não posso
>   vê-lo, porque eu dou o comando SUPER + ESPAÇO e escrevo o nome de um
>   programa e pressiono enter, o programa abre.

Comment: Are you reported this bug? I don't find it in the list on launchpad...

Answer (score 1):

I had enabled hot corner in the top left corner, so that was the first movement to the position of the apps menu was opened several times causing an error in the application menu.

**SOLUTION**

I disabled the hot corner in the top left corner.

> **Português:**
>   Eu havia habilitado hot corners no canto superior esquerdo, isso fazia 
>   que com o primeiro movimento para a posição do menu de aplicativos
>   fosse aberta varias vezes causando um erro no menu de aplicações.
>
> SOLUÇÂO
>
> Desabilitei o hot corners no canto superior esquerdo.

Comment: I have the same issue, but your solution not work for me :(

Comment: `pkill slingshot`

Comment: neither disabling the hot corners nor the pkill command for slingshot above worked for me but `pkill wingpanel` did